Puppeteer Error in NestJS Docker-Compose Setup: "qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'"
I'm using NestJS with Puppeteer to generate PDFs in a Docker-Compose application. However, when I try to send an email with an attached PDF, I encounter the following error:
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "timestamp": "2024-11-12T19:42:25.236Z",
    "path": "/api/mail-service/sendingPdfToEmail",
    "message": "Failed to launch the browser process!\nqemu-x86_64: Could not open 
    '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: 
    https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting\n"
}

The error is reproduced on the local machine and the Debian 11 server.
Here’s the method for sending the email:
async sendPDFFormToEmail(email: string, filename: string, offerForm: any, invoiceForm: any, html: any, options?: PDFRenderOptions) {

        this.logger.log('Try to open puppeteer browser...');
        this.logger.log('Loading here...');
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            // executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',
            headless: 'new',
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        });

        this.logger.log('Try to open browser new page...');
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        this.logger.log(`Load HTML...`);
        await page.setContent(html, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
            timeout: 0,
        });

        await this.emulateMediaType(options, page);

        this.logger.log(`Generate PDF...`);
        const pdfContent = await page.pdf(options.page);

        let subject = '';
        let customerName = '';
        let address = '';
        let originalInvoice = null;
        if(offerForm?.orderAddresses?.length > 0) {
            const orderAddress = offerForm?.orderAddresses[0];
            if(orderAddress?.contactCustomer?.length > 0) {
                const contact = orderAddress?.contactCustomer[0];
                customerName = `${contact?.firstName} ${contact?.lastName}`;
            }
            address = `${orderAddress?.address?.street }, ${orderAddress?.address?.zipCode} ${orderAddress?.address?.city}`;
        }
        if(invoiceForm !== null) {
            if(invoiceForm?.isAdditionalInvoice) {
                const address = `${offerForm?.invoiceAddress?.street }, ${offerForm?.invoiceAddress?.zipCode} ${offerForm?.invoiceAddress?.city}`;
                subject = (invoiceForm?.statusId === 4 ? "Stornorechnung " : "Zusatzrechnung ") + invoiceForm?.invoiceNumber + " - " + address;
            } else {
                if(invoiceForm?.isCorrection) {
                    const prefix_invoice = invoiceForm?.isCorrection ? (invoiceForm?.type === 0 ? "Rechnung " : invoiceForm?.type === 1 ? "Anzahlungsrechnung " : invoiceForm?.type === 2 ? "Endabrechnung " : 'Stornorechnung ') : "Stornorechnung ";
                    subject =`${prefix_invoice} ${invoiceForm?.invoiceNumber} - ${customerName}, ${address}`;
                } else {
                    if(invoiceForm?.originalInvoiceId !== null) {
                        originalInvoice = await this.prismaService.invoice.findFirst({ where: { id: invoiceForm?.originalInvoiceId } });
                        if(originalInvoice !== null) {
                            subject = `Storno Ihrer Rechnung Nr. ${originalInvoice?.invoiceNumber} - Stornorechnung Nr. ${invoiceForm?.invoiceNumber}`;
                        } else {
                            subject = `Storno Ihrer Rechnung Nr. ${originalInvoice?.invoiceNumber}`;
                        }
                    } else {
                        subject = `Storno Ihrer Angebot Nr. A-${offerForm?.offerNumber} - Stornorechnung Nr. ${invoiceForm?.invoiceNumber}`;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            const address = `${offerForm?.invoiceAddress?.street }, ${offerForm?.invoiceAddress?.zipCode} ${offerForm?.invoiceAddress?.city}`;
            subject =`Ihr persönliches Angebot A-${offerForm?.offerNumber} - ${customerName}, ${address}`;
        }
        await this.mailerService.sendMail({
            to: email,
            subject: subject,
            template: 'email-template',
            context: {
                from: '"No Reply" <noreply@example.com>',
                to: email,
                filename: filename,
                offerForm: offerForm,
                invoiceForm: invoiceForm,
                originalInvoice: originalInvoice
            },
            attachments: [
                {
                    filename: filename,
                    content: pdfContent,
                    encoding: 'base64',
                    cid: 'pdfDocument'
                }
            ],
        });

        this.logger.log(`Close Browser...`);
        await browser.close();
        return pdfContent;
    }

Dockerfile
I’m using node:18-buster and have included all dependencies required by Puppeteer:
# -----------------------------------------------
# Stage 1: Builder - Compile the Application
# -----------------------------------------------
FROM node:18-buster AS builder

# Install build tools and dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        chromium \
        python3 \
        netcat \
        mariadb-client \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV=development

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package files and install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy application code
COPY . .

# Build the NestJS application
RUN npm run build

# -----------------------------------------------
# Stage 2: Production - Final Image
# -----------------------------------------------
FROM node:18-buster-slim AS production

# Install dependencies required for Puppeteer and Chromium
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
        chromium \
        fonts-liberation \
        libasound2 \
        libatk1.0-0 \
        libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
        libc6 \
        libcairo2 \
        libcups2 \
        libdbus-1-3 \
        libdrm2 \
        libexpat1 \
        libfontconfig1 \
        libgbm1 \
        libgcc1 \
        libglib2.0-0 \
        libgtk-3-0 \
        libnss3 \
        libpango-1.0-0 \
        libx11-6 \
        libx11-xcb1 \
        libxcb1 \
        libxcomposite1 \
        libxcursor1 \
        libxdamage1 \
        libxext6 \
        libxfixes3 \
        libxi6 \
        libxrandr2 \
        libxrender1 \
        libxss1 \
        libxtst6 \
        xdg-utils \
        ca-certificates \
        fonts-ipafont-gothic \
        libappindicator3-1 \
        lsb-release \
        netcat \
        mariadb-client \
        curl \
        wget \
        unzip \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV=production \
    PUPPETEER_CACHE_DIR=/home/node/.cache/puppeteer

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package files
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies
RUN npm ci

# Create Puppeteer cache directory and set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.cache/puppeteer && chown -R node:node /home/node/.cache

# Change ownership of the app directory
RUN chown -R node:node /app

# Switch to non-root user
USER node

# Install Puppeteer's Chromium as node user
RUN npx puppeteer install

# Copy the Prisma schema files
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/prisma ./prisma

# Generate Prisma Client in the production stage
RUN npx prisma generate

# Copy built application from builder
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/initial_data.sql ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/entrypoint.sh ./

# Ensure the entrypoint script has the correct permissions
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

# Create 'uploads' directory if required by the app
RUN mkdir -p ./uploads/images

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 3001

# Set the entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

# Start the application
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]

Troubleshooting So Far
I've followed the troubleshooting guide from Puppeteer and installed the dependencies for Puppeteer in both the builder and production stages, but the error persists. I also tried setting executablePath in puppeteer.launch(), but that didn’t help.
Additional Information
puppeteer version: 21.11.0
Node version: node:18-buster (Docker)
Running on Docker Compose
How can I resolve this Puppeteer issue with missing ld-linux-x86-64.so.2?

Also when I uncomment: // executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium', it fails with same error

You can [edit] your post to include more info. Did you see the canonical thread by chance? Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer
